# My PC isn't turning on at all, only GPU LED is lit

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power

I've had this custom build for 6 months and only today has this happened. I shut off the computer to go out and upon returning the computer will not power on at all when pressing the button.

The green LED on my GPU shows that the PSU and MB are not dead as it's recieving power.

**What I have tried**

- Unplugging and then plugging back in all PSU cables connected to the motherboard
- Reseated the System Panel connectors and made sure they are the right way

Comment: Start by trying a different, known-good power supply.

Comment: Its a corsair VS550, so its very well known, also as the GPU LED is it, it shows that there is power and that the PSU is functional

Comment: You should still try another PSU as @Techie007 suggested. I have had experience with working but faulty PSU + GPU combination, where only 3D application caused error (BSOD, or something like that), replacing PSU was solution. So in my case the PSU was in "working" order but didn't provide enough juice for 3D.